Adding php-imagick extension to Alpine Docker container fails
I try to add the imagick php extension to my Docker container:
FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine AS base

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS imagemagick imagemagick-dev \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && apk del .build-deps

The process fails with the following error:
14.37 PHP-Parser-5.0.0/phpstan.neon.dist
14.38 Saved /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/ImagickPixel_arginfo.h
14.38 Parse /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/Imagick.stub.php to generate /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/Imagick_arginfo.h
14.41 In /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/Imagick.stub.php:
14.41 Unterminated preprocessor conditions
14.41 make: *** [Makefile:196: /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/Imagick_arginfo.h] Error 1
14.41 ERROR: `make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserAclDeF/install-imagick-3.7.0" install' failed
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS imagemagick imagemagick-dev     && pecl install imagick     && docker-php-ext-enable imagick     &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear     && apk del .build-deps" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


Looks like it is related to the couple imagick / PHP 8.3. There are solution on that issues, as it seems: https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/643; namely It seems like people install it without pecl: https://gist.github.com/Wirone/d5c794b4fef0203146a27687e80588a6#file-workaround-dockerfile

not working solution

Well, the workaround found here
Instead of

RUN pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

run this one:

RUN curl -L -o /tmp/imagick.tar.gz https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/archive/7088edc353f53c4bc644573a79cdcd67a726ae16.tar.gz 
&& tar --strip-components=1 -xf /tmp/imagick.tar.gz 
&& phpize 
&& ./configure 
&& make 
&& make install 
&& echo "extension=imagick.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini 
&& rm -rf /tmp/*

Works for me.
